# How to simulate a window-like content area cutout in HTML5 + CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, layout, css

[image: Content layout]

I have an interesting content layout proposal but I'm having difficulty figuring out how it can work. 
Inside the "content box" container, we want to be able to animate (using jQuery) elements being scrolled out of view, becoming hidden once they have touched the edge of the content box, almost as if the content box was a window.

This would be trivial if the Logo box above the content was attached to the content box (assuming elements are moving upward) and entirely opaque, because then its z-index could be set higher and elements that are animated towards it would slide under it. Obviously, right now the elements just fly out of the content box and are seen on top of everything.

Even if the Logo box was inside another div that was connected to the content box, it would need to have the same background image as the body in order  to still appear transparent and hide the elements heading towards it trying to become hidden. This obviously can't work because the image being used for the logo-containing div and the body wouldn't line up.

So it seems as though what we're looking to do isn't feasible, but let's hear what you have to suggest. We're looking to use HTML5 + CSS3 for this project.

Comment: css `clip` might help, although having lots of content in the layout box and then just sticking it with a certain width and height and as david mentions below is worth a try as well.

Comment: Yeah, Unfortunately clip seems pretty painful to use. It might work, but I would need some jQuery magic and math to get it to work correctly, since clip only works on the (absolutely positioned) element, and not a container. I would need to figure out where the bounds I want are in relation to my object and then have negative values, if that's even allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content box is set to `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative` any elements inside it should be hidden when outside the bounds of the box, even if they are absolutely positioned.

Here is a jsFiddle illustrating: http://jsfiddle.net/c8LHL/

Comment: Maybe it's because the animated elements are absolutely positioned, but overflow: hidden seems to have no affect.

Comment: @Sam.Rueby Can you post some sample code? What you are asking sounds pretty standard and I am sure I can point you in the right direction - maybe make a jsFiddle showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks. My container didn't have its position set to relative.